# Should this question marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

This question I posted a few minutes ago has been marked as duplicate.

[What is the best solution without using ComplexType?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815840/register-in-db-not-the-entire-class-but-only-two-property)

The fact is I am asking for the best way to register two properties from a class who is a property of an other object.

In the original question, it's about **how to ignore the property when object is register**.

Could you see the difference? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Why not ping DavidG and ask him?

Comment: I see you edited your question to remark that your question is different from the other one. However “Please, read my question in detail.” is _not an explanation_ for why this is the case.

Comment: Your question specifically states that you know how to solve it, so I'm not even sure what you're asking.  You know how to solve your problem, so you don't have a problem to solve.

Comment: I closed the question (you could have pinged me there to save asking on meta). I'm more than happy to re-open the question if I've done it incorrectly, but your question is vague enough that it looked like a direct duplicate. We can have the technical discussion on the question instead of here.

Comment: Sorry but I thought that my explanation was enough explicit. That's why I wrote to "read" my question. Well, it's more clear now

Comment: @Coemgen4 Clearly your question *wasn't* clear enough, given that people weren't able to understand it.  Given that people *didn't* understand it, telling them to just "understand it anyway" isn't helpful; you need to be clearer.

Comment: You're right, my bad :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was the user who closed the question. I'm always more than happy to re-open the question if I've done it incorrectly, but your question is vague enough that it looked like a direct duplicate.

Upon deeper inspection, it now looks like your post is actually a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906950/using-complextype-in-entity-framework-core) because you are asking for a feature of Entity Framework Core that is not yet implemented. So using the recently released feature of Stack Overflow, I've edited the list of duplicates and switched it to this one instead.

PS You could have pinged from your question to save asking on meta.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, it's exactly a duplicate from the question that you are related. But not from the first, it's not the same. So, don't be so fast to mark a post :). I was not enough precis but a comment could had been more useful. That's why my lack of understanding

Comment: @Coemgen4 person reviewing question had to make a decision for unclear question - downvote+close as unclear  or guess reasonable duplicate. Note that it is advised not to comment on downvotes (because many posters immediatly start replying like "can't you read @#$#") - so you'll receive way less information from downvote rather than duplicate.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You bring up a very good point there. Closing as duplicate gives an extra set of information. Not only the answers of the target, but how the original question appears to the observer.